# OpenMP overhead with a very parallel loop

Tags: fortran, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize a loop with OpenMP where each iteration is independent (code sample below).

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(PRIVATE)
do i = 1, 16

  begin = omp_get_wtime()

  allocate(array(100000000))

  do j=1, 100000000
    array(j) = j
  end do

  deallocate(array)

  end = omp_get_wtime()

  write(*,*) "It", i, "Thread", omp_get_thread_num(), "time", end - begin

end do
!$END OMP PARALLEL DO
```

I would except a linear speedup out of this piece of code, with each iteration taking as much time as in the sequential version, as there are no possible race conditions or false sharing issues. However, I obtain the following results on a machine with 2 Xeon E5-2670 (8 cores each):

With only one thread:

```
It           1 Thread           0 time  0.435683965682983     
It           2 Thread           0 time  0.435048103332520     
It           3 Thread           0 time  0.435137987136841     
It           4 Thread           0 time  0.434695959091187     
It           5 Thread           0 time  0.434970140457153     
It           6 Thread           0 time  0.434894084930420     
It           7 Thread           0 time  0.433521986007690     
It           8 Thread           0 time  0.434685945510864     
It           9 Thread           0 time  0.433223009109497     
It          10 Thread           0 time  0.434834957122803     
It          11 Thread           0 time  0.435106039047241     
It          12 Thread           0 time  0.434649944305420     
It          13 Thread           0 time  0.434831142425537     
It          14 Thread           0 time  0.434768199920654     
It          15 Thread           0 time  0.435182094573975     
It          16 Thread           0 time  0.435090065002441
```

And with 16 threads :

```
It           1 Thread           0 time   1.14882898330688     
It           3 Thread           2 time   1.19775915145874     
It           4 Thread           3 time   1.24406099319458     
It          14 Thread          13 time   1.28723978996277     
It           8 Thread           7 time   1.39885497093201     
It          10 Thread           9 time   1.46112895011902     
It           6 Thread           5 time   1.50975203514099     
It          11 Thread          10 time   1.63096308708191     
It          16 Thread          15 time   1.69229602813721     
It           7 Thread           6 time   1.74118590354919     
It           9 Thread           8 time   1.78044819831848     
It          15 Thread          14 time   1.82169485092163     
It          12 Thread          11 time   1.86312794685364     
It           2 Thread           1 time   1.90681600570679     
It           5 Thread           4 time   1.96404480934143     
It          13 Thread          12 time   2.00902700424194
```

Any idea where the 4x factor in the iteration time is coming from ?

I have tested with both the GNU compiler and the Intel compiler with the O3 optimization flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure I've covered that topic before, but since I cannot seem to find my earlier posts, here I go again...

Large memory allocations on Linux (and possibly on other platforms) are handled via anonymous memory mappings. That is, some area gets reserved in the virtual address space of the process by calling `mmap(2)` with flags `MAP_ANONYMOUS`. The maps are initially empty - there is no physical memory backing them up. Instead, they are associated with the so-called *zero page*, which is a *read-only* frame in physical memory filled with zeros. Since the zero page is not writeable, an attempt to write into a memory location still backed by it results in a segmentation fault. The kernel handles the fault by finding a free frame in physical memory and associating it with the virtual memory page where the fault has occurred. This process is known as *faulting the memory*.

Faulting the memory is a relatively slow process as it involves modifications to the process' PTEs (page table entries) and flushes of the TLB (Translation Lookaside Buffer) cache. On multicore and multisocket systems it is even slower as it involves invalidation of the remote TLBs (known as *remote TLB shootdown*) via expensive inter-processor interrupts. Freeing an allocation results in removal of the memory mapping and reset of the PTEs. Therefore, the whole process is repeated during the next iteration.

Indeed, if you look at the effective memory bandwidth in your serial case, it is (assuming an array of double precision floats):

```
(100000000 * 8) / 0.435 = 1.71 GiB/s
```

Should your `array` be of `REAL` or `INTEGER` elements, the bandwidth should be cut in half. This is nowhere the memory bandwidth that even [the very first generation of E5-2670](http://ark.intel.com/products/64595/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2670-20M-Cache-2_60-GHz-8_00-GTs-Intel-QPI) provides.

For the parallel case, the situation is even worse, since the kernel locks the page tables while faulting the pages. That's why the average bandwidth for a single thread varies from 664 MiB/s down to 380 MiB/s for a total of 7.68 GiB/s, which is almost an order of magnitude slower than the memory bandwidth of a single CPU (and your system has two, hence twice the available bandwidth!).

A completely different picture will emerge if you move the allocation outside of the loop:

```
!$omp parallel default(private)
allocate(array(100000000))
!$omp do
do i = 1, 16

  begin = omp_get_wtime()

  do j=1, 100000000
    array(j) = j
  end do

  end = omp_get_wtime()

  write(*,*) "It", i, "Thread", omp_get_thread_num(), "time", end - begin

end do
!$omp end do
deallocate(array)
!$omp end parallel
```

Now the second and later iterations will yield twice shorter times (at least on E5-2650). This is because after the first iteration, all the memory is already faulted. The gain is even larger for the multithreaded case (increase the loop count to 32 to have each thread do two iterations).

The time to fault the memory depends heavily on the system configuration. On systems that have THP (transparent huge pages) enabled, the kernel automatically uses huge pages to implement large mappings. This reduces the number of faults by a factor of 512 (for huge pages of 2 MiB). The above cited speed gains of 2x for the serial case and 2.5x for the parallel one are from a system with THP enabled. The mere use of huge pages decreases the time for the first iteration on E5-2650 to 1/4 (1/8 if your array is of integers or single-precision floats) of the time in your case.

This is usually not the case for smaller arrays, which are allocated via subdivision of a larger and reused persistent memory allocation known as *arena*. Newer memory allocators in glibc usually have one arena per CPU core in order to facilitate lock-less multithreaded allocation.

That is the reason why many benchmark applications simply throw away the very first measurement.

---

Just to substantiate the above with real-life measurements, my E5-2650 needs 0.183 seconds to perform in serial one iteration over already faulted memory and 0.209 seconds to perform it with 16 threads (on a dual-socket system).

Comment: Thank you for you very detailed answer.

Answer (score 4):

The speed of the operation

```
  do j=1, 100000000
    array(j) = j
  end do
```

is limited not by the [ALU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit) speed but by the memory bandwith. Typically, you now have several channels to the main memory per CPU socket available, but still smaller number then the number of cores.

Also the allocation and deallocation are memory access bound. I am not sure whether there may be also some synchronization needed for the `allocate` and `deallocate`.

For the same reason, the STREAM benchmark http://www.cs.virginia.edu/stream/ gives different speed-ups than purely arithmetically intensive problems.

Comment: Correct answer +1. Would just like to add that I ran into a similar problem in my own code where the speed-up factor for increasing numbers of threads diminished after I was saturating the memory bandwidth. I was able to optimize further by taking advantage of caching throughout the code. This obviously cannot be done for OP's case, but it might be useful to someone else stumbling upon this question/phenomena later.

Comment: Actually, in that particular case, the overhead from faulting the memory is the limiting factor, not the memory bandwidth. I would guess that the OP's kernel does not implement transparent huge pages as my slower E5-2650 is 4x/8x faster than the OP's E5-2670 because of THP.

Comment: Yeah, I was quite sure there are problems associated with the allocations, but I didn't know the details, hencece only one careful sentence.

Answer (score 1):

They're not independent. Allocate/deallocate will be sharing the heap.

Try allocating a bigger array outside of the parallel section, then timing just the memory access.

It's also a non uniform memory architecture - if all the allocations come from one cpu's local memory, access from the other cpu will be relatively slow as they get routed via the first cpu. This is tedious to work around.

Comment: Actually, presuming that the OP is running Linux, it is very unlikely that the heap is ever shared. glibc has been providing lock-free memory management via per-core memory arenas since very long time. Also, larger memory allocations are directly implemented as anonymous mappings - nothing shared (besides the process page tables).

Comment: Interesting - that would significantly reduce the motivation for tc_malloc et al. Do you have a reference readily available?

Comment: ptmalloc2 has been part of glibc since version 2.3.x. (circa 2006). The per-core arena feature was there in the source but not enabled initially in all distributions, e.g. definitely not in Debian and Ubuntu. The original motivation behind tcmalloc was that ptmalloc2 never moves memory between arenas, which is probably still the case. As for using anonymous mappings for large allocations, that seems a pretty common thing. AFAIK, FreeBSD uses the same strategy.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the background